# Scala: Predicate does not hold Exception

Tags: scala, for-loop

What does this exception mean in Scala:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Predicate does not hold for ...
```

Comment: Is it being used in a for-comprehension?

Comment: Actually, yes, it does appear to happen within one of the statements inside the for comprehension, never making it to the body.

Comment: can you paste the full error and the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's specific to [scala.util.Try](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L241)

```
scala.util.Try(2).filter(_ < 0) // Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException: Predicate does not hold for 2)



  for {
    v <- scala.util.Try(2)
    if v < 0
  } yield v // Failure(java.util.NoSuchElementException:
```

Answer (score 7):

One way this can be caused is if you have a for-comprehension that combines a Try with a predicate (`if` statement):

```
for {
  x <- Try(expr) if booleanExpr
} {
  ...
}
```

The `filter` method of Try can throw a java.util.NoSuchElementException to skip the loop body if `booleanExpr` evaluates to `false`.

The `reason` field of that exception is "Predicate does not hold for ..."

As @Guillaume points out in the comments, it's the implementation of Try that causes this by the way it implements `filter` -- the method that's called by the compiler when you use a conditional (if) within a `for comprehension`:

```
if (p(value)) this
else Failure(new NoSuchElementException("Predicate does not hold for " + value))
```

Comment: Please specify the source of that information. As far as I know, `if` inside `for` is transpiled into `withFilter`. Never heard about throwing `NoSuchElementException` to skip loop body.

Comment: @Aivean https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L241

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé, I see. Brent's answer made false impression that this is related to `for` comprehension, while it's all about `filter` of `Try`.

Comment: @Aivean thank you. When I've encountered this error, I was using `x <- Try(expr)`, so that explains it. I'll update my answer.